# Block words in url by squid

Tags: http, url, https, proxy, squid

I would like to block any request to any site (or at least google) that contains for example "drink" in URL.
So for example https://www.google.com/search?q=drink&oq=drink&aqs=chrome..69i57j46i512l2j0i512l3j46i512j0i512l2.3207j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 would be blocked.

If there is a way to redirect it to custom 403 page it would be great.

Thanks in advance for any help.